# How to tell PyCharm that class instance can be interpreted as integer via __index__ method when passed to range() as an argument?

Tags: python, class, pycharm, integer, warnings

Consider the following example:

```
import random


class Class:
    def __index__(self):
        return random.randint(-100, 100)


c = Class()
print(range(c, c, c))
```

It runs correctly and prints something like `range(11, -29, -77)`. But PyCharm warns me that `Expected type 'int', got 'Class'` 3 times, on every `c` passed as an argument to `range`. I want to get rid of this warning by explaining to PyCharm that it is OK to pass `Class` instance to `range` as an argument. I tried to declare `Class` as subclass of `numbers.Integral` to show that `Class` really implements an integer type but it didn't help, modified example:

```
import random
import numbers


class Class(numbers.Integral):
    def __index__(self):
        return random.randint(-100, 100)

    __int__ = __index__  # it doesn't help either

    __abs__ = None  # they all must be overloaded because they are abstract in numbers.Integral
    __add__ = None
    __and__ = None
    __ceil__ = None
    __eq__ = None
    __floor__ = None
    __floordiv__ = None
    __invert__ = None
    __le__ = None
    __lshift__ = None
    __lt__ = None
    __mod__ = None
    __mul__ = None
    __neg__ = None
    __or__ = None
    __pos__ = None
    __pow__ = None
    __radd__ = None
    __rand__ = None
    __rfloordiv__ = None
    __rlshift__ = None
    __rmod__ = None
    __rmul__ = None
    __ror__ = None
    __round__ = None
    __rpow__ = None
    __rrshift__ = None
    __rshift__ = None
    __rtruediv__ = None
    __rxor__ = None
    __truediv__ = None
    __trunc__ = None
    __xor__ = None


c = Class()
print(range(c, c, c))
```

The warning is still there. Do you have any idea how to deal with it?

Answer (score 1):

According to [[Python 3.Docs]: Data model - object.**__index__**(*self*)](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__index__):

> **Note**: In order to have a coherent integer type class, when [__index__()](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__index__) is defined [__int__()](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__int__) should also be defined, and both should return the same value.

But as seen in the question, this is not new info. Below, I tried different alternatives.

### 1. Code changes

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import random
from typing import SupportsInt


def _randint():
    return random.randint(-100, 100)


class C0:
    def __index__(self):
        return _randint()


class C1:
    def __index__(self):
        return _randint()

    __int__ = __index__


class C2(SupportsInt):
    def __index__(self):
        return _randint()

    __int__ = __index__


class C3(int):
    def __index__(self):
        return _randint()

    __int__ = __index__


def main():
    c0 = C0()
    c1 = C1()
    c2 = C2()
    c3 = C3()

    print(c1.__class__.__name__, list(range(int(c1), c1)))
    print(c2.__class__.__name__, list(range(int(c2), c2)))
    print(c3.__class__.__name__, list(range(int(c3), c3)))
    print(c0.__class__.__name__, list(range(int(c0), c0)))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {0:s} {1:d}bit on {2:s}\n".format(" ".join(item.strip() for item in sys.version.split("\n")), 64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    main()
    print("\nDone.")
```

[image: Img0]

**Notes**:

- Apparently, *PyCharm* code inspector doesn't do a deep enough inspection
- Explicitly convert the objects to *int*. Personally, I see this as a workaround, and as far as I'm concerned the warning absence doesn't justify it. Anyway, it doesn't work for *C0* objects, which will raise an exception
- **Extending *int* does the trick**. But again, I don't know if it worth doing that just to get rid of the warning

### 2. *PyCharm* settings

[image: Img1]

Disable *Python -> Type checker* inspection. As seen, **it does the trick too**. But it also hides some genuine errors (e.g. `int(c0)` is no longer highlighted, but it **is wrong**). So, from what am I concerned, this can do more harm than good. 
Maybe you can leave it active, but play with its settings to narrow down its effect. More details on [[JetBrains]: Code inspections](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/code-inspection.html#Code_Inspection.xml) .

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I also searched `typing` and hoped that there could be something similar to `SupportsInt` like `SupportsIndex` which can help.

Comment: Apparently extending from *typing* doesn't help. The only thing that works with no major side effects is extending *int*.

Comment: I upvoted your answer because it is useful in general but I was looking for something without inheriting from int and without defining `__int__` and converting with `int()`. I hoped that PyCharm inspections can see that instance of a class that defined `__index__` can be used in `range()` constuctor. So I didn't mark your answer as accepted to leave the question open.

Answer (score 0):

Since `range.__init__` is declared as accepting `int`s only (see [typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/2and3/builtins.pyi#L1082)), there is no way to say that `C` is acceptable.

Feel free to suppress inspection locally:

```
c = Class()
# noinspection PyTypeChecker
print(range(c, c, c))
```